# JavaCV deployment

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I have some experience with Java and want to start playing with JavaCV. All of the documentation seems overwhelming so I'll try to ask some of my general questions here.

1.) I will be programming in Windows. I assume how it will work is I need to install OpenCV in my computer so that Java can import it?

2.) If I were to install OpenCV in my computer, does that mean the user who uses the app needs to install OpenCV on his computer as well? What if it was a mobile phone, how does it work then?

Thanks in advance

Comment: before you do so, consider using opencv's own java wrappers instead of the 3rd party javacv ones, which are based on quite outdated opencv usage..

Comment: You could start by looking at the info for the opencv tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags/opencv/info. Your 1st question is answered there.